# Onsager relations in Hall conductivity

Tags: transport-phenomena

For Onsager relation $\sigma_{ij}(B)=\sigma_{ji}(-B)$, why should one flip the sign of the $B$-field for reciprocity?

In the case of antiferromagnetism, with zero net magnetic moment, can the Onsager relation be used $\sigma_{ij}(B)=\sigma_{ji}(-B)$ directly instead $\sigma_{ij}(B,M)=\sigma_{ji}(-B,-M)$?

Comment: are you asking *why* should one flip the sign of the $B$-field for reciprocity?

Comment: Yes, actually it is my another question, could you please give me some explanation?

Comment: OK, but I think you should clarify your problem first and then the question will be reopened to accept answers.

Answer (score 2):

*Onsager relations* (and Onsager-Büttiker relations in quantum transport) follow from the time-reversal symmetry of the laws of physics. Magnetic fields being pseudo-vectors change their direction under the time-reversal transformation - hence the sign-flip.

**Remark:**
[Onsager reciprocal relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onsager_reciprocal_relations) relate the components of the tensors for linear response coefficients in a bulk media. In their original form the derivation involves statistical averaging (also referred to as *"regression of fluctuations"* in some texts.) They are also valid for interacting systems.
Onsager-Büttiker relations are an application of Onsager relations to transport in nanostructures, within the context of [Landauer-Büttiker formalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landauer_formula). These do not require thermodynamical averaging, but simply grounded in the properties of the scattering matrix (time-reversal symmetry and unitarity.) However, as the formalism itself, they are for non-interacting case.